# fgets not working properly

Tags: c, string, io, file-handling, fgets

I wanted to learn how fgets works. For this I wrote code to print "hi" before every line, which is going to be printed from an another text file named input.txt using fgets.

But it is showing 2 `hi`s between consecutive lines instead of 1. I can't understand why?

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char singleline[150];//storing each line of input.txt as singleline arrays.
    FILE *fp;//file pointer named fp.
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");//reading the text file input.txt
    while (!feof(fp)){
        fgets(singleline,150,fp);
        printf("hi\n");// to check that before each line hi is printed?
        puts(singleline);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**My text file**

```
rohit sharma,batsman,1,35.0,40.0,2200,20,95  
viru,batsman,2,28.0,45.0,1800,02,75   
suresh raina,batsman,3,38.0,35.0,2300,15,98  
suryaky,batsman,4,30.0,0.0,500,0,10   
abd,batsman,5,37.2,0.0,1200,0,50
dhoni,batsman,6,45.2,0.0,2100,0,85  
albie,allrounder,7,24.87,27.65,945,80,86  
ashwin,bowler,8,8.82,24.37,150,82,85  
naraine,bowler,9,6.67,16.94,40,67,49  
johnson,bowler,10,12.25,21.33,98,45,33  
starc,bowler,11,14.17,28.71,85,14,14
```

**Output**

```
hi   
rohit sharma,batsman,1,35.0,40.0,2200,20,95   

hi
hi  
viru,batsman,2,28.0,45.0,1800,02,75   
(till the end)  
johnson,bowler,10,12.25,21.33,98,45,33  

hi 
hi  
starc,bowler,11,14.17,28.71,85,14,14
```

*What is the error here?*

Comment: Is that the exact output? Also [`while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1983495). Also, you don't check if `fopen()` succeeded which obviously didn't happen since there is something being read, but it's a bad idea to ignore that, apart from that I am unable to believe that given your input file, the output is the one you posted.

Comment: I've just checked - `fgets()` works just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted gives:

```
hi
rohit sharma,batsman,1,35.0,40.0,2200,20,95  

hi
viru,batsman,2,28.0,45.0,1800,02,75
```

as expected, since you do not eat the trailing newline. You can do it by adding this line after reading into `singleline`.

```
if(strlen(singleline) != 0) // because you may have an empty file
  singleline[strlen(singleline) - 1] = '\0';
```

You could also do it like alk suggested:

```
singleline[strcspn(singleline, "\n")] = 0;
```

taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2411320) answer.

Also `feof()` in the control statement of the while loop makes me redirect you to this question: [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Thanks alk and iharob for the useful comments.

Comment: This will not work because strlen itself relies on the null terminator!

Comment: Did you downvote @d3l? `fgets()` will put a null terminator and this works.

Comment: @d3l "*strlen itself relies on the null terminator*" this correct, but there **is** a  `0`-terminator.

Comment: @alk with a 2nd glance at the code I will agree with you. However, this is the output I got..I will check!

Comment: `strlen() - 1` is dangerous as long one cannot make sure the parameter passed to `strlen()` does not refer to a `0`-length "string".

Comment: @G.Samaras I always find that the safest thing to do with `strlen()` is to store it's value. And then use it correctly by checking what that value is.

Comment: @alk, it is because of `puts`.  Writes the C string pointed by str to the standard output (stdout) and appends a newline character ('\n'). iharod agreed,

Comment: Oh yes, its `puts()` not `fputs()`, my bad. The latter does not append a new-line.

Comment: @alk that made me refresh my memory about `puts()`, so no bad at all, thanks! ;)

Comment: A save and very elegant way to cut off any kind of traling new-line is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/694576